# How to configure nginx for django with gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have successfully run gunicorn and confirmed that my web runs on localhost:8000. But I can't get nginx right. My config file goes like this:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 104.224.149.42;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    }
```

104.224.149.42 is the ip for outside world.

Comment: What exactly is not working right? Do you have any specific errors?

Comment: Did you check Nginx's configuration file?
You can force nginx to check your settings file using the following command:
nginx -t -c /path/to/configuration/file.conf

Comment: @PanchoJay The command is quite useful and gives error message as follows: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed.  Then after searching in google, I added http tag to enclose server tag and get error message: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration.  Probably I should look into the document.

Comment: @Borg I think your are placing your settings on an incorrect file.
The code you pasted should be placed in the site configuration file, not in nginx.conf.
Did you use a tutorial or guide?

Comment: @PanchoJay I got it working. It seems that soft link in sites-enabled does not work even though all the tutorials online suggest linking config file from sites-available. Copying works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Do this

- Remove `default` from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Create `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my.conf` with following

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 104.224.149.42;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Then `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.conf`

- restart `nginx`

You have to configure `static` files and `media` files serving.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to completely delete the default site configuration.
Just deleting default from sites-enabled should work.